# For the problem statement, my solution shows that time limit exceeds the given one. Can it be made shorter?

Tags: python, string, list

You are given *n* words. Some words may repeat. For each word, output its number of occurrences. The output order should correspond with the input order of appearance of the word. See the sample input/output for clarification.

Note: Each input line ends with a "\n" character.

**Constraints:**

1<n<10^5

The sum of the lengths of all the words do not exceed 10^6,

All the words are composed of lowercase English letters only.

**Input Format**

The first line contains the integer, *n*.
The next *n* lines each contain a word.

**Output Format**

Output 2 lines

On the first line, output the number of distinct words from the input.

On the second line, output the number of occurrences for each distinct word according to their appearance in the input.

```
n=int(input())
cake=[]
for i in range(n):
    cake.append(input())
ans1=len(set(cake))
cakez=list(set(cake))
boo=[]

for i in range(ans1):
    boo.append(cake.count(cakez[i]))

booz=map(str,boo)

print(ans1)
print(' '.join(sorted(booz,reverse=True)))
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we aren't a tutoring service

Comment: Doing `cake.count()` for every single unique word adds a lot of time, since it has to search the entire list. Isn't there some way you could keep counts while going through the list only once? (hint: use a `dict`) (bigger hint: `collections.Counter`)

Answer (score 1):

The `list.count` method costs *O(n)* in time complexity, so calling it in a loop over `n` iterations would result in a time complexity of *O(n ^ 2)*.

Instead, you can build a dict of counters with `collections.Counter` from the given words so it would cost *O(n)* in time complexity by taking advantage of the *O(1)* lookup time of a dict:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(input() for _ in range(int(input())))
print(len(c))
print(*c.values())
```